# Suggest me an iscsi server which supports adding a target at runtime

Tags: iscsi

Default iscsitarget requires to restart the whole server after editing the `/etc/iet/ietd.conf`. This is a problem as if, any iSCSI target is being read/wrote the server restart will make every operation fail.

Moreover I would need to programmatically interact with this server (in java) and, from what I saw, iscsitarget doesn't provide any library/api to do so..and initiators don't contemplate this operation.

So, I believe some other vendor created an iSCSI server more suited to my needs, do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

> This is a problem as if, any iSCSI target is being read/wrote the server restart will make every operation fail.

It depends on what platform you're on, but the SCSI protocol involves the initiator [performing a retry](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.kernelext/doc/kernextc/scsi_error_rec.htm) on the operation in the event of a failure.

But the [jSCSI](http://jscsi.org) initiator also contains an iSCSI target (server) component.